# Swift 2D array with Sprites

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, 2d

I have been out of the loop with swift for a while and I'm stuck with an Array problem.
I get the feeling I'm approaching it all wrong and I was doing this to clean up repetitive code. I have a loop within a loop which seems to be working with the exception that when I output I get all 4 iterations from the first loop which in a way is fine as I want all for but I want to put them in a variable before the second iteration starts... I hope this makes sense and I could be miles of the way I'm doing it any help would be appreciated.

```
struct Action {
static var arraySprites :[SKTexture], [SKTexture]()
static var Idle = [SKTexture]()
}
var actions = ["idle", "walk", "run", "jump"]
var sprites = ["Idle", "Walk", "Run", "Jump"]
for (e1, e2) in zip(actions, sprites) {
    
    let e1Atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "\(e2)")
    var e1Frames: [SKTexture] = []
    let e1Images = (e1Atlas.textureNames.count-1)
    for i in 0...(e1Images) {
     let sprite = String(format: "%03d", i);
     let e1Texture = "\(e1)\(sprite)"
     e1Frames.append(e1Atlas.textureNamed(e1Texture))
     }
    /*gives me all four iterations of the for loop I want to somehow get iteration 1,2,3,4 and assign them to glabal variables*/
 print(e1Frames[0])
}
```

Update : I came to this solution although a bit crude I'm still getting to grips with this... I'm (Very) open to better methods this spits out 4 arrays of sprites for different actions...

```
        let sprites = ["idle", "walk", "run", "jump"]
        for (index, action) in sprites.enumerated() {
            let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "\(action)")
            var frames: [SKTexture] = []
            let images = (atlas.textureNames.count-1)
            for i in 0...(images) {
                let sprite = String(format: "%03d", i);
                let texture = "\(action)\(sprite)"
                frames.append(atlas.textureNamed(texture))
            }
            switch (index) {
            case 0:
                playerIdle = frames
            case 1:
                playerWalk = frames
            case 2:
                playerRun = frames
            case 3:
                playerJump = frames
            default:
                print ("Default")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Let me clarify, you want the outer loop (with zip) executes 4 times. Then save `e1Atlas` and `e1Images` to use later on the inner loop. However, you want the outer loop to be done 4 times before executing the inner loop, don't you? Btw, the `Sprites` is just a capitalized of `Actions`, Why don't you `.capitalized` for each action instead of zip 2 arrays together?

Comment: Your `Actions` and `Sprites` array look like a good candidate for an enum with a string rawvalue. You probably want to declare a dictionary outside of your `for` loop and put the array of textures for each sprite into that dictionary which is keyed by the sprite

Comment: @son Yeah I realized today with a fresh head that a lot of things are a bit "Bended" in the code I simplified it a bit in playground but the root of the problem is still there I create a loop with 2 iterations from a array with lets say "pete" "John" basically inside that there is a loop that lets say counts to 10 That spits out pete1 pete2 etc. after that it spits out john1 john2 etc. I want to catch the array or the list pete1-10 put it away for later use in a variable and do the same with john 1-10

Comment: @Paulw11 I have not looked at enum with rough values I will dive into that cheers for the tip...

Comment: @son @Paulw11 To Simply the code if you paste this in Playground you will see the Offset 0 Offset 1 etc. How do I capture the array offset 0 or offset 1 for example for use intead of the 4 iterations combined?
code `import UIKit
struct character {
    //static var Animals = [String]()
}
var figures = ["Pooh", "Dumbo", "Donald", "Mouse"]
for(disney) in figures.enumerated() {
    for i in 0...10 {
        print (disney)
     }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to end up with is an array of textures for each of the different action states, *idle*, *walk*, *run*, *jump*.

I would create an `enum` for these states with a string raw value.

You can then create a dictionary of texture arrays keyed by the enum values.

```
enum Action:String, CaseIterable {
    case idle="idle"
    case walk="walk"
    case run="run"
    case jump="jump"
}


var actionSprites = [Action:[SKTexture]]()

for action in Action.allCases { 
    let e1Atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: action.rawValue)
    var textures = [SKTexture]()
    for i in 0..<e1Atlas.textureNames.count {
        let imageNumber = String(format: "%03d", i);
        let textureName = "\(action.rawValue)\(imageNumber)"
        textures.append(e1Atlas.textureNamed(textureName))
    }
    actionSprites[action] = textures
}
```

Once you have this you can find the textures for a specific action, say run, using `actionSprites[.run]`

Comment: Thats Brilliant thank you I wasn't far off I just couldn't get it right really helps a lot